# JMeter: How do you run code that's not part of a sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I want to run code at the beginning that sets up variables, but as far as I can tell, the options for running code are:

1. Sampler: Appears in JMeter reports and screws up my numbers.
2. Pre-processor/Post-processor/Assertion: Must be attached to existing sampler.
3. Timer: This works sometimes, but it appears that if you have your timers higher in the tree than your samplers, they just get ignored.
4. Listener: Runs after your samplers (I want this code to run before everything else).

Is there a way to run code without modifying reports or attaching it to a sampler?

Comment: It really depends on what you are actually trying to do, so more details would help. One of the most basic things is to use **setUp Thread Group**, however it won't fit any sort of setup...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler to the place in the Test Plan where you want to run your code
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the Test Action sampler
3. Tick `Cache compiled script if available` box
4. Put your code into `Script` area

This is something you're looking for as

- [Test Action sampler will not be reflected in the load report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers):

  > Each sampler (except Test Action) generates one or more sample results.
- Currently [Groovy is the best scripting option available in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

  [image: JMeter Test Action Sampler]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Test action is now replaced by `Flow Control Action`

Answer (score 1):

See [Execution order](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder):

> 1. Configuration elements
> 2. Pre-Processors
> 3. Timers
> 4. Sampler ...

For example of Configuration element

> The User Defined Variables Configuration element is different. It is processed at the start of a test, no matter where it is placed.

Inside it you can execute [JMeter functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) which include numerous options as to read from CSV, execute groovy or [beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) **code**...

Comment: "Inside it you can execute" - it is not clear how to add code to `User Defined Variables Configuration`.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov inside Value column you can add function call as `${__groovy(123*456)}`

Answer (score 1):

You can add your action as a Sampler (no matter JSR223 or anything else) and then add a PostProcessor that will mark this Sampler's result as ignored. It can be done with JSR223 PostProcess with groovy script:

```
prev.setIgnore()
```

You can also control whether or not to ignore this sample based on the conditions.